# Background thread factory pattern

Tags: java, android, multithreading, factory

I'm writing an Android application that uses objects that are expensive to create (instantiation can take up to 100ms). The user experience is degraded if the main thread is blocked while and object is created.

I'd like to have a pool of objects ready for use by the main thread. If the pool is empty, the main thread should block while an object is created on a background thread. If the pool has an object already available, it should be returned and a new one created, ready for use the next time the main thread needs one.

Is this a well known boilerplate pattern?

Comment: This sounds like a variation on the Bridge Pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern

Comment: If there's a possibility to block the main UI thread, you should design a separate state for it anyway, for example to show "Please wait" progress and doing the new object initialization in background. Though 100ms delay on main thread may be acceptable without that. Al least it doesn't throw an ANR ))